# How to provide client certificate to swagger inspector

Tags: swagger, swagger-inspector

https://inspector.swagger.io/builder

I have an api hosted locally and needs a client certificate for authentication. I am able to access the API from Fiddler and Postman. For both these I could add the client certificate needed to authenticate with the api. I am not sure how I can provide this client certificate to swagger inspector. Any idea?

I see following error message:
The request has been terminated.

Possible reasons for the error:

Network error: the host is unreachable
Certificate problem: https is specified, but the service is using a self-signed, expired, or otherwise problematic certificate
CORS error: the requested service does not allow requests from other domains. Please try adding the Swagger Inspector Extension in chrome, since it can resolve this issue.
The Swagger Inspector Extension may be disabled. Please try enabling it by going to: chrome://extensions.